# How to display all result after use For/Next

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a new sheet to display all cell has Hyperlink outsource, but in this For its just display the last result, not all results.

```
Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim Ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim s As Byte

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Hyperlink").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Hyperlink"

For Each Ws In Worksheets
r = 1
    For Each Rng In Ws.UsedRange
        If InStr(Rng.FormulaLocal, "[") Then
            Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Cells(r, 2).Value = Ws.Name
            Cells(r, 3).Value = Rng.Address
        End If
     Next Rng
r = r + 1
Next Ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
MsgBox "Hoan thanh.", , "Nguyen Duc Thinh - 093 23456 19"

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that if you turn them off `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` you need to turn them on again or they stay off forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'd better increment your variable r inside the if-statement, not outside.

Like this:

```
For Each Rng In Ws.UsedRange
    If InStr(Rng.FormulaLocal, "[") Then
        Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Cells(r, 2).Value = Ws.Name
        Cells(r, 3).Value = Rng.Address
        r = r + 1
    End If
 Next Rng
```